# Script works when running it with breakpoints in Firebug, not otherwise, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I have several textareas which I want to apply keyup listeners to. This is my script:

```
$( "textarea" ).each( function(){
    $(function(){
        $( this ).keyup( function(){
            console.log(123); // This line only gets called if I set breakpoints
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is that the console never prints out anything. However, if I put in breakpoints in Firebug, the script reaches the console.log line, and it works fine, which is weird. How can I solve this?

Comment: Inside the `$(function(){`, `this` is not what you think it is.  You need to wrap the `each` in `$(function(){`, not the other way around.

Comment: That code makes no sense, do you even know what `$(function(){})` does?

Comment: @epascarello: From what I understand it makes sure the dom is loaded before continuing the script.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Doesn't seem to make any difference. Still not working.

Comment: @FoadFarkhondeh: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/UPtFr/

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Apparently so. Then it makes even less sense why my code isn't working for me.

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?  Does other JavaScript work?  Do you have the `.each` inside the `$(function(){` like I suggested (like the code in the jsFiddle I posted)?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Yes I tried your way with the exact same result. That is: Working when I set breakpoints. Not working when I don't. No other JS errors. It feels like when I don't set breakpoints it "goes too fast" and not everything is loaded properly.

Comment: Don't know what to tell ya then.  I've never used breakpoints, so I don't know what's going on.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: The weird part is that it still doesn't work even if I copy&paste your exact jsfiddle example. I guess there's something else going on and it's not the codes fault.

Comment: *From what I understand it makes sure the dom is loaded before continuing the script.* Correct, but if you already found the textareas than the code should have already been loaded! Makes no sense in how you are using it. If you care about the DOM being loaded, it would be around the textarea selection part!

Comment: Did you try Tushar's code? It works just fine for me. Also ensure you have the latest versions of Firefox and Firebug, i.e. currently 25.0 and 1.12.4.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$( "textarea" ).keyup( function(){
     console.log(123); 
});
```